# OpenFOAM simpleFoam calculation of flow around object leads to strange result

Tags: cfd

I calculated the flow around an object using OpenFOAM's `simpleFoam` and wanted to evaluate it's drag coefficent. Actually the drag coefficient is in a reasonable range for the object so I thought the simulation went well. However when I looked at the flow fields they appear to have some strange diagonal artefacts in them.

The mesh I used looks like this where the flow is coming from the left. It is refined near the object

[image: Mesh]

The resulting pressure field looks for some reason like this:

[image: Resulting pressure field]

And the velocity field like this:

[image: Resulting velocity field]

The flow is coming from the left with a uniform velocity of ~0.03. This corresponds roughly to a Reynolds number of 800 for the object. The calculation was done in laminar mode and the following interpolating schemes where used:

```
ddtSchemes
{
    default         steadyState;
}

gradSchemes
{
    default         Gauss linear;
    grad(U)         cellLimited Gauss linear 1;
}

divSchemes
{
    default         none;
    div(phi,U)      bounded Gauss linearUpwindV grad(U);
    div(phi,k)      bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,epsilon) bounded Gauss upwind;
    div(phi,omega)  bounded Gauss upwind;
    div((nuEff*dev2(T(grad(U))))) Gauss linear;
}

laplacianSchemes
{
    default         Gauss linear corrected;
}

interpolationSchemes
{
    default         linear;
}

snGradSchemes
{
    // Korrigiert für Non-Orthogonalität
    default         corrected;
}

wallDist
{
    method meshWave;
}
```

For the solvers the following set-up was used:

```
solvers
{
    p
    {
        solver          GAMG;
        tolerance       1e-8;
        relTol          0.01;
        smoother        GaussSeidel;
    }

    Phi
    {
        $p;
    }

    U
    {
        solver          smoothSolver;
        smoother        GaussSeidel;
        tolerance       1e-8;
        relTol          0.1;
        nSweeps         1;
    }

    k
    {
        solver          smoothSolver;
        smoother        GaussSeidel;
        tolerance       1e-8;
        relTol          0.1;
        nSweeps         1;
    }

    epsilon
    {
          solver          smoothSolver;
          smoother        GaussSeidel;
          tolerance       1e-08;
          relTol          0.1;
            nSweeps         1;
    }

    omega
    {
        solver          smoothSolver;
        smoother        GaussSeidel;
        tolerance       1e-8;
        relTol          0.1;
        nSweeps         1;
    }
}

SIMPLE
{
    nNonOrthogonalCorrectors 0;
    consistent      yes;
}

potentialFlow
{
    nNonOrthogonalCorrectors 10;
}

relaxationFactors
{
    equations
    {
        U               0.9;
        k               0.7;
        epsilon         0.7;
        omega           0.7;
    }
    fields
    {
        p               0.8;
    }
}

cache
{
    grad(U);
}
```

What could cause these strange diagonal patterns?

EDIT: As suggested by the comments, I increased the distance between the object and the surrounding walls. However I still got the same issue with the diagonal fragments.

[image: Velocity field with distant walls]

[image: Pressure field with distant walls]

Comment: Just at a glance, it looks like the wind tunnel should be made taller, so there's more room for flow to develop around the model - the mesh also looks quite coarse in the wake - I'd refine this a little. How long did it take to run 'as is'? Would it be fairly easy to run again with these changes?

Comment: What are the boundary conditions at the walls? It looks like flow could be reflecting off them? If they are non-penetrable boundaries, then they need to be *much* further from the object...

Comment: Hi, @JonathanRSwift thanks for your comment. Right now I have slip boundary condition for the velocity at the four walls of the channel and zeroGradient boundary condition for pressure. I can try a calculation where the walls are further away from the object, that should not be too much work. I will post the results of that as soon as I'm done.

Comment: To add something that has not been said yet; Perhaps the numerical method is oscillating on its solution and what you are seeing is noise from that, there are methods to circumvent that which are ENO and WENO (essentially non oscillatory) which are already used in grid methods with good results. I do not know if openfoam has an ENO method already implemented.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift I increased the distant between the object and the wall, but unfortunately I still got the issue with the diagonal fragments. You also suggested to refine the mesh in the wake of the object. I will do this next.

Comment: Did you run `checkMesh`? The mesh looks very bad. You mentioned running a laminar case, however, you have $k$, $\omega$, $\epsilon$ and $\nu_{eff}$ in your dictionaries. also you could be having Von-Karman vortices in the wake of the body and steady solution might not exist. And how are you defining $\text{Re}$?, this is quite tricky.

Comment: And is that Blender's Suzanne?

Comment: Hi @Algo sorry for my late reply. Yes this is Blender's Suzanne. I actually haven't looked at this case for quite a while. I had the turbulent properties in the dictionaries, because I also wanted to try a turbulent calculation. These entries shouldn't be used if I choose a laminar solver, right?

Comment: If you are running a laminar case, then you need to make sure that `simulationType` is set to `laminar` in `turbulenceProperties` dictionary. I suggest that you include more details about your boundary conditions and mesh statistics.